# Adding a dependency to library on Kotlin in full Java-project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library

I created a simple library (`AAR`) on the `Kotlin`, when called up, interacts with the other application through the `Broadcast` mechanism. And now I had a question: how to properly connect it to third-party developers, as a `file` (not Maven), that them do not have to install a dependency on the `Kotlin`?

Comment: Kotlin is compiled to Java byte code. The AAR you create does not matter if it created from either Kotlin or Java.

Comment: Has, if not establish a dependency, then get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics

Answer (score 1):

You cannot: Kotlin compiles to class files and executes on the JVM, yes... But they depend on the Kotlin runtime...  Also note that your Gradle dependencies are not nested forward, meaning that either you include the jars (causing duplicate clases conflicts if the end user wants to use the same library) or you inform in the docs. Alternatively you can use a private Maven repository that can include a file with nested dependencies.